# Add Expires Header in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, header

Now I am trying to implement High web site performance following YSlow rules. In terms of Expires Header, I have configured in nginx like the following:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)\?[0-9]+$") {
    expires max;
    break;
}
```

Yes, I got the good result because I could not see css and javascript files followed by timestamp at the end of file any more and it passed, but I still  have problems with images which are retrieved from another domain. They still have no expires. Anyone knows how to deal with this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't affect the expires headers of images served from other domains; the configuration of those assets is up to the administrator of the domain that is serving them.

Comment: but what if I would like to add expire header to those images. Can I do that?

Comment: only if you control the server the images are delivered from

Comment: Sure, I tested a while ago, I noticed first request was from the sever but later it was from cache. However, in YSlow Add Expire headers still fails. Any idea?